# Loading specific columns of a TXT file to a MySQL database table

Tags: mysql, database, text

I have a table in a MySQL database with the following fields (columns):

`ID, FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3`

And a TXT file in the following format:

`A`   `1`   `[`

`B`   `2`   `]`

`C`   `3`   `.`

`D`   `4`   `,`

Columns are separated by `\t`.

I would like to store the data from the file's first column in `FIELD1` and from the third column in `FIELD3` without changing other column's values.

Is there a way of doing it using MySQL own commands (like "Load")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LOAD DATA INFILE`. Check my example below:

```
LOAD DATA
    INFILE 'file_name'
    INTO TABLE tbl_name
    CHARACTER SET utf8
    FIELDS
      TERMINATED BY '\t'
    (ID, FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3) 
    SET 
      your_col_name = FIELD1,
      your_other_col = FIELD3
```

Comment: Thanks! In "your_col_name", can I put "1" for the text first column?

Comment: whatever you give as a name is fine except the reserved words. I you feel that this answer is useful please consider to mark it as answer so that community can benefit from it. Regards